# Coordinates as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point, coordinates

I have a table which stores some POIs, so it has some id, name, latitude and longitude. The problem is, that I don't want to have the POIs with same coordinates in the database twice. The possibilities I thought of are these:

- Make primary key as a combination of latitude and longitude... but they are floats, so it's not a good idea
- create column INT(16) (8 numbers from latitude and 8 from longitude merged together), but it's like duplicating the data, and it'll take up lot of space
- make some hash from the latitude and longitude, and set it as primary key, but I'm afraid it'll be big number too

How could it be done, so it will not take up much space in db?

Comment: 1. Why are they floats? Is DECIMAL inappropriate? 2. I suggest you make them DECIMAL and set a UNIQUE KEY on (lat,lon). Unless you're sure that the coordinates never 'move', it's probably best not to use them as a PK.

Comment: If your coordinates are floating-point data and they have errors from previous calculations which means that coordinates that would ideally be equal are not equal, then converting them to another form or hashing them will not generally produce equal results. You must first resolve whether coordinates refer to the same point or not. Why do you think your floating-point data might not have equal values for the same point?

Answer (score 1):

longitude and latitude each can be converted to 4 byte integer by multiplying each with 1e7 (ten millions).
This then is an integer giving all precision you need (3cm).

Now combine these two 4 byte integer to one 8 byte long.

I am not sure if the Database supports long, probably yes.